# RxJS Resolve a sequence of observables where each depends on the previous ones

Tags: rxjs6

I need to make a series of http calls, where each call depends on the previous responses (bodies or headers). How can I achieve this with Observables?

So far I've made the ugly nested subscriptions:

```
this.http.get(url1)
.subscribe(response1 => {
    const params1 = something(response1);
    this.http.post(url2, params1)
    .subscribe(response2 => {
        const params2 = something(response1,response2);
        this.http.post(url3, params2)
       .subscribe(response3 => {
           const params3 = something(response1,response2,response3);
           this.http.post(url4, params3)
           .subscribe(response4 => {
               const params4 = something(response1,response2,response3,response4);
               this.http.post(url5, params4)
               .subscribe(response5 => console.log(response5));
           });
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the flatmap rxJS operator for better readability. I think it would look like the following. rxJS6, you will need to use the pipe operator for this to work.

**Simpler Example**

Here is a more built up example solution to understand whats going on.

```
public test(): Observable<any>
{
    return of([1]);
    //when subscribed to returns [1]
}

public testTwo(value): void
{
    console.log(value); // [1] <- comes from the observable
    this.fromEndpoint = value;
}

public testThree(example): Observable<any>
{
    if (example[0] === 1)
    {
        return of([3]);
        // return an array of [3] when subscribed to.
    }
}

public ngOnInit()
{
    this.test().pipe(flatMap(response1 => (this.testTwo(response1), 
    this.testThree(response1)))).subscribe(final => 
    {        
        console.log(final); 
        // this logs ['3'] as the calls are chained with flatMap
    }); 
}
```

Im hoping the more simple example I have put together will make it a little easier to understand. That leads me to think you could do the following for the code you have provided.

**Solution**

```
this.http.get(url1).pipe(
  flatMap(response1 => (this.exampleFunction(response1), this.http.get(response1))),
  flatMap(response2 => (this.responseValue = response2, this.http.get(response2))),
  flatMap(response3 => (this.exampleFunctionThree(response3), this.http.get(response3)))
).subscribe(final => {
    console.log(final);
    console.log(this.responseValue);
});
```

Note that the `console.log(final);` will only log the result of the last observable / api call and not collect values along the way. if you needed to collect all the values, you can pass in a separate function to send the response to, or declare it as you go along in a higher scope. I have shown that in the above example.

**Documentation**

[flatmap and switchmap](https://medium.com/@w.dave.w/becoming-more-reactive-with-rxjs-flatmap-and-switchmap-ccd3fb7b67fa)

[of and subscriptions as they are used in example](https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-to-read-the-rxjs-6-sources-part-1-understanding-of-and-subscriptions-694e7d9def6b)

[flatMap is an alias for mergeMap!](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! Two questions: 1) the symbol between the flatMap(s) is a dot (like chain) or is a comma (the arguments of pipe function)? 2) In my use case, for instance the last http.get call needs ALL the previous responses, not only the last one; how would I achieve that?

Comment: Its a . (dot), Ill be honest until seeing this question I hadn't really thought about this. A put in an edit, it seems you can pass in a function with each response. I would use this to do what you need with each value. even if it just sets your value to a declared variable. That way you have access to it. Actually hang on another edit.

Comment: where functions can be passed in, you can set the response to a higher scope so then where you have access to final you can also use the other responses. Hope that makes sense :-)

Comment: I understand, I may create an object in the main function (the whole function which wraps the http calls), and populate such object by each http call response, and in this way the next http calls can access this object to read the already stored responses. Have I got your idea?

Comment: Thats what I think :-), I think the syntax i have at the very bottom isnt quite correct. just a min.

Comment: dropped an edit, sorry my bad was commas, all wrapped up in the pipe. Be sure to let me know if this approach works, the first example I made was fine, tested in a stack blitz.